# CakePHP: Can't login when using Members Controller instead of Users Controller

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have a really strange issue that I simply cannot figure out anymore. I setup a cakephp project and I was using a Users controller to handle authentication and everything was working perfectly, 100%. However, I decided to drop the Users controller, model and views and replace it with my Members one because Members will be my primary users with one or two Admin's that need to login.

What I have now in my Members model, controllers and views are identical to what I had in the Users but by default CakePHP wants to use the Users model and users table. I did a lot of debugging and eventually got CakePHP to use Members instead of Users but now I simply cannot login as I keep getting the ***Your username and password is incorrect, please try again*** error message.

Here's what I have by way of code, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

### AppController.php

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member';
    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Member');
    $this->Auth->allow(array('view', 'index', 'add', 'edit', 'delete'));
}

public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Time'); 

public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Cookie',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'members',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Your username and password is incorrect, please try again.',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password',
                'scope' => array('Member.deleted' => '0')),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What's important to note about the `beforeFilter()` is that I've tried the plural and singular of Member and I also added the `$this-Auth->allow()` function so that I could edit my user's password in the Members table to make sure that my password was being hashed correctly.

As another note, everywhere I look I have seen that when using the `loginAction` it should look like this:

```
'loginAction' => array(
    'controller' => 'Members',
    'action' => 'login',
    'plugin' => 'members'
),
```

The problem with using the above is that my URL structure ends up looking like `/members/Members/login` hence I have omitted the plugin key-value pair in my AppController which I'm guessing is probably where the error lies.

### Member.php

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (!empty($this->request->params['admin'])) {
            return $user['role'] === 'admin';
    }
    return !empty($user);
}

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data['Member']['password'])) {
        $this->data['Member']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Member']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

### MembersController.php

```
public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username and password is incorrect, please try again.'));
        } // end if cannot log in
    } // end if no form submitted
} // end login

public function logout() {
    $this->Session->destroy();
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

### /Members/login.ctp

```
<div id="page-content" class="span9">
    <div class="users form">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Member', array('inputDefaults' => array('label' => false), 'class' => 'form form-horizontal')); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <h2><?php echo __('Member Login'); ?></h2>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->label('username', 'username', array('class' => 'control-label'));?>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' => 'span12')); ?>
                    </div><!-- .controls -->
                </div><!-- .control-group -->
                <div class="control-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->label('password', 'password', array('class' => 'control-label'));?>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'span12')); ?>
                    </div><!-- .controls -->
                </div><!-- .control-group -->
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('auto_login', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => 'Remember me?')); ?>
            </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

As I say, any help would be amazing as I've gone through just about everything I know to try and get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach type of group I want to login (eg. Administrator, User or any other type) you have to write the next things in your controller and models:

Lets say you have two types of users with different platform to access, like administrators and users

In Controller/AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers/')
            )
        ),
        'Session');
```

In Model/Administrator.php

```
 public function beforeSave() {
        if (isset($this->data['Administrator']['password'])):
            $this->data['Administrator']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Administrator']['password']);
            return true;
        endif;
    }

 public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

 public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['Administrator']['group_id'])) {
        $groupId = $this->data['Administrator']['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
    }
    if (!$groupId) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
    }
}
```

In Controller/AdministratorsController.php beforeFilter()

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers/', 'userModel' => 'Administrator'));
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Administrator'));

$this->Auth->loginAction = array(/*YOUR PATH HERE*/);
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(/*YOUR PATH HERE*/);
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(/*YOUR PATH HERE*/);
```

**If you have this for all your groups it should work great!

I have three types of groups: Administrators, Shops and Users and this works for me!**

Comment: You just have to create a DB, Controller and Model foreach of your group type and foreach one you will have instead of 'Administrator' your model name, as in my case "Shop", "User" or even "Member"

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable contribution. I obviously don't have three user types like yourself but the principal around what you've proposed has worked great for me. I thank you again for taking the time to help me out here! Much appreciate.

Comment: I've found a better way to do this, even with multiple login types see this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13168148/1421518)

Answer (score 1):

Have you [read this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)? If not do it now.

The example there is pretty clear:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Member')
);
```

You have to specify the model the Form authentication adapter should use.

For the redirect issue, define

```
$this->Auth->redirectUrl = array(/* Whatever you need here */);
```

Comment: I did read it and tried the following in my AppController:

`'authorize' => array(
'controller',
'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers', 'userModel' => 'Member'),
),`

But I'll try the above now

Comment: I didn't actually rename the files. I have a members and *had a users table of which I've built my models and controllers from that. My initial users table just handled authentication while my members contained a whole bunch more in terms of details about the members. Trust me, I wouldn't choose to go outside of the norm with Cake and I'd much rather have stuck with Users if that made sense for this project.

Comment: Ok, so I added the code you suggested but the results are not much different to the implementation I did for this in the Auth components array. What is happening now however is going to the site redirects you to _/members/pages/login_ instead of _/members/login_

Comment: $this->Auth->redirectUrl needs to be set to whatever it should redirect to after login.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the beforeFilter of your AppController.php file

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'login');
```

This should direct your application to the right url to login.